# R shiny addition of points according to input

Tags: shiny, addition

I want to create an application where inputs are matched with a score. Here is my code:

```r
library (shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(fresh)
library(htmltools)
ui<-navbarPage("Addition of points",
       tabPanel("Calculation",
                
                fluidPage(                            
                  headerPanel(h4("Scores")), 
                  headerPanel(h5("Please select your inputs.")),
                  
                  fluidRow(
                    (column (3, 
                             
                             headerPanel(h5(strong("Score1"))),
                             
                             sliderInput("score1", label = h6("Score1 (1-3), input <=2 should add 6 points to the total score, input >2 should add no points"), min = 1, max = 3, value = 1, ticks = TRUE, animate=TRUE, step = 1, width = "150px")                                      
                             
                    )),
                    (column (3,
                             
                             headerPanel(h5(strong("Score2"))),
                             
                             numericInput("score2", label = h6("Score2, input <=10 should add 5 points to the total score, input >10 should add no points"), value = "1" , width = "150px")
                             
                    )),
                    (column (3,
                             headerPanel(h5(strong("Score3"))),
                             radioButtons("score3", label = h6("Score3, clicking on 'No' should add 4 points to the total score, clicking on 'Yes' should add no points"), choices = list("No"=1, "Yes"=2), selected = character(0))
                             
                             
                    )),
                    (column (2,                                         
                             wellPanel(
                               style = "background: white", 
                               headerPanel(h4(strong("Score:"))),                                             
                               textOutput("multi")                                             
                             )))
                  )))
)
server<-function(input, output) {
    B=function(x, y){
        if(input$score1<=2) {+6}
        if(input$score2<=10) {+5}
        if(input$score3==1) {+4}
    }
    output$multi <- renderText ({ B() })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can anyone help with the function how to add the points to the total score? The maximum total score would be 15 points. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this short and tidy server expression:

```r
library (shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(fresh)
library(htmltools)
ui<-navbarPage("Addition of points",
       tabPanel("Calculation",
                
                fluidPage(                            
                  headerPanel(h4("Scores")), 
                  headerPanel(h5("Please select your inputs.")),
                  
                  fluidRow(
                    (column (3, 
                             
                             headerPanel(h5(strong("Score1"))),
                             
                             sliderInput("score1", label = h6("Score1 (1-3), input <=2 should add 6 points to the total score, input >2 should add no points"), min = 1, max = 3, value = 1, ticks = TRUE, animate=TRUE, step = 1, width = "150px")                                      
                             
                    )),
                    (column (3,
                             
                             headerPanel(h5(strong("Score2"))),
                             
                             numericInput("score2", label = h6("Score2, input <=10 should add 5 points to the total score, input >10 should add no points"), value = "1" , width = "150px")
                             
                    )),
                    (column (3,
                             headerPanel(h5(strong("Score3"))),
                             radioButtons("score3", label = h6("Score3, clicking on 'No' should add 4 points to the total score, clicking on 'Yes' should add no points"), choices = list("No"=1, "Yes"=2), selected = character(0))
                             
                             
                    )),
                    (column (2,                                         
                             wellPanel(
                               style = "background: white", 
                               headerPanel(h4(strong("Score:"))),                                             
                               textOutput("multi")                                             
                             )))
                  )))
)
server<-function(input, output) {
    B <- reactive({
        0 + 
            (if(!is.null(input$score1) && input$score1<=2) 6 else 0) + 
            (if(!is.null(input$score2) && input$score2<=10) 5 else 0) +
            (if(!is.null(input$score3) && input$score3==1) 4 else 0)
    })
    output$multi <- renderText ({ B() })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```